# Using global costmap as local costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

Is there a possibility to use a global costmal as local costmap?
I have a simulation of my robot and a map (which was mapped with the real robot). Using the navigation stack I am able to drive around in my map loaded by the map server.

But now I want to see if it works as well in the real map with local obstacles assunimg nothing changed in the global costmap, the local costmap should be exactly the same or am I wrong? I just want to test this once or temporary, using the real robot I will use the local costmap generated by the real sensors.

So is there a possibility to feed the local planner with the global costmap as local costmap?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239517/using-global-costmap-as-local-costmap/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use the same config for the local and global costmap and they should be the same.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thanks this worked perfectly!